# memtest86+ crashes while running

Tags: linux, memory, crash, hardware-failure, memtest86+

I have a core i5-3230M CPU with a DDR3 RAM of 4Gb and I ran memtest86+, but when it gets on test 3 it crashes abruptly showing weird characters all over the screen. 
[image: Follows a screen photo.]

Is my RAM damaged or some other component?

Comment: that does look very unusual, i've never had a problem like that with memtest. have you tried a different stick of RAM ?

Comment: No. I don't have another one. Just a 2Gb ram from my old PC which I'm not certain is compatible with my laptop.

Comment: Surely you’ve tried other things/programs/OSs: Do they work? Did you try memtest86 (non-plus)?

Comment: You should try to test with another stick and for the current one try using default BIOS settings and see if you get different results.

Comment: i think the simplest option would be to try a different stick of RAM. or the same stick of RAM in a different computer, at least